# RegEx version control

Tags: javascript, strings, node.js, regex, ecmascript-6

this is my first time on this stack exchange :)

I created a little script to check for the latest version of specified API version available, but I am wondering if I am using the best way possible for checking regex and includes?

The `var arr` will be filled dynamically with version folders using fs.readdir, but for simplicity I wrote them in the array manually and the `var pattern` will come from `req.params.v` using nodejs express router middleware.

Just looking for an approval or if there is a better way, thank you!

```
var arr = ['v1.0.0', 'v5.2.4', 'v5.2.9', 'v5.20.4', 'v6.4.0'];
var pattern = 'v5.2';

const regex = /^v[0-9](\.[0-9]{1,2})?(\.[0-9])?$/;

if (regex.test(pattern) && (arr.filter(s => s.includes(pattern)) != 0)) {

    if (pattern.match(/\./g) == null) {
        console.log('major version');
        console.log(pattern);
    } else if (pattern.match(/\./g).length == 1) {
        console.log('minor version');
        console.log(pattern);
        pattern = pattern + '.';
    } else {
        console.log('patch version');
        console.log(pattern);
    }
    const matches = arr.filter(s => s.includes(pattern));
    console.log(matches[matches.length - 1]);

} else {
    console.log('Specify correct API version!');
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 6 → 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// const fs = require('fs');
// const folder = "../api/";
const regex = /^v[0-9](\.[0-9]{1,2})?(\.[0-9])?$/;

// let files = fs.readdirSync(folder);
let pattern = "v5.2"; // let pattern = req.params.v;

var arr = ['v1.0.0', 'v5.2.4', 'v5.2.9', 'v5.20.4', 'v6.4.0']; // var arr = [];

/** Function **/
/*
function naturalSort(a, b) {
    var ax = [],
        bx = [];

    a.replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function (_, $1, $2) {
        ax.push([$1 || Infinity, $2 || ""])
    });
    b.replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function (_, $1, $2) {
        bx.push([$1 || Infinity, $2 || ""])
    });

    while (ax.length && bx.length) {
        var an = ax.shift();
        var bn = bx.shift();
        var nn = (an[0] - bn[0]) || an[1].localeCompare(bn[1]);
        if (nn) return nn;
    }

    return ax.length - bx.length;
}

files.forEach(file => {
    let dirStat = fs.statSync(folder + '/' + file).isDirectory();
    if (dirStat) {
        arr.push(file);
    }
});

arr.sort(naturalSort);
*/
/**/

if (regex.test(pattern)) {

    pattern = (function () {
        let patternRegexMatches = pattern.match(regex);

        if (patternRegexMatches[1] === undefined) {
            console.log('major version');
            console.log(pattern);
        } else if (patternRegexMatches[2] === undefined) {
            console.log('minor version');
            console.log(pattern);
            pattern = pattern + '.';
        } else {
            console.log('patch version');
            console.log(pattern);
        }

        return pattern;
    })();

    let matches = arr.filter(s => s.includes(pattern));

    if (matches.length != 0) {
        console.log(matches[matches.length - 1]);
    } else {
        console.log('Specify correct API version!');
    }

} else {
    console.log('Specify correct API version!');
}
```

Thanks to the review, I updated my code with the following improvements:

1. let patternRegexMatches = pattern.match(regex);
   Only match 1x and only if there is a pattern submitted
2. pattern = (function() ...
   return pattern
3. Only 1x arr.filter(s => s.includes(pattern));

Additionally, in javascript the folder structure is not "naturally sorted" as with ls -v on linux, so I added an additional function to make sure the version folders are sorted correctly.

Answer (score 3):

### Likely logic flaw

In the first conditional:

> ```
> if (regex.test(pattern) && (arr.filter(s => s.includes(pattern)) != 0)) {
> ```

[`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) "creates a new array"<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)</sup> so the second conditional expression compares an array with zero. Those two should never be loosely equal so that conditional always evaluates to `true`. Perhaps you intended to check the `length` property of the array.

### Improving efficiency

The code has repeated operations - e.g. `arr.filter(s => s.includes(pattern))` appears twice, and then there are multiple calls to `pattern.match()`. The call to `arr.filter()` could be stored in a variable and then used whenever needed instead of re-filtering.

Also, the regular expression stored in `regex` could be used with [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get an array of matches. Because the regular expression has capturing groups, those capturing groups can be used instead of calling `pattern.match(/\./g)` multiple times to check for the number of dots. Instead, check if the array returned by `String.match()` isn't `null` and then if the 2nd and 3rd elements are `undefined`.

See a comparison in [this jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/repeat-tests-vs-match).

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter</sub>

Comment: There is a flaw in your code, namely specifying v5.2 should return the latest of minor version 2, namely v5.2.9 and not v5.20.4 (minor version 20)

Comment: I have updated my code, see edit. According to jsperf (thank for you that website!) it is the fastest way.

Comment: Darn I missed that part about updating the pattern when there is a minor version detected. I have removed that snippet since it isn't the same.